# Is it normal for a USB OTG converter to show in lsusb

Tags: usb, usb-on-the-go, command-line, terminal

When running `lsusb` (not as root) with an OTG adapter plugged in without anything plugged into it I get :

```
u0_a83@flounder:/ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
```

Is this normal with USB OTG adapters.

Also a USB hub is recognized as another device in `lsusb` when plugged using OTG

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  Are you encountering an issue?

Comment: Aren't they just converters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is absolutely normal.  The host controller can detect the presence of the cable since pins 4 & 5 are bridged.

On my device I ran `lsusb` with a USB key connected via OTG, then with only the OTG cable connected, then with nothing:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1221:3234
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003
$ lsusb
```

Exactly as expected.  Your device appears to have one more bus compared to mine.

Comment: My device has two buses when nothing is plugged in (not even the OTG , NOTHING)

Comment: @SuiciDoga There's no hard requirement that they need to be disabled; it doesn't matter.

Comment: My device is a Nexus 9